# Bootstrap modal form field autofocus does not working for seond time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal, autofocus

Im using bootstrap modal(Bootstrap version 3.2.0) in my rails application

In that i have add autofocus for form field .For first opening the modal it automatically focus the field.But the second time it does not working .

here i added some code

```
<button type="button" id="myModalCreateButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
                        Create New Project
</button>
```

The form in modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title second-color" id="myModalLabel">Create New Project</h4>
        </div>
        <%= form_for(@newproject) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group single-field">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Project Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newProjectField" placeholder="Enter project name" name="project[project_name]" autofocus >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createProjectButton" autofocus >
                Create
            </button>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```